# list index out of range which is an IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am not able to understand why I am getting this particular error while running my python file:

```
def main():

 # Creating Spark context object
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Fake Opinion Detector")
    spark = SparkSession(sc)

    # Loading dataset files
    meta_data = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1]).map(lambda x: x.split("\t")).toDF(["user_id","prod_id","rating","label","date"])
    review_data = sc.textFile(sys.argv[2]).map(lambda x: x.split("\t")).toDF(["user_id","prod_id","date","review"])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
20/04/04 14:09:30 WARN Utils: Your hostname, user-Lenovo-G50-70 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.43.58 instead (on interface wlx00e04d0cbda4)
20/04/04 14:09:30 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/04/04 14:09:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FakeOpinionDetection.py", line 369, in <module>
    main()
  File "FakeOpinionDetection.py", line 321, in main
    meta_data = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1]).map(lambda x: x.split("\t")).toDF(["user_id","prod_id","rating","label","date"])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well, try to convince me that there *shouldn't* be an error, by going through the line a step at a time. For example, what are you expecting the value of `sys.argv` to be? Now, did you *check* that?

Comment: Break up those long lines into individual, simpler statements.  Then you can see which one is causing the error.

Comment: For what it's worth, it *looks* like `sys.argv[1]` is probably the culprit, which means you forgot to pass the required command-line arguments, and in your program you forgot to check if they were missing (you should always check).

Comment: @TomKarzes that means, how to recorrect it??

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when i print sys.argv its showing the name of python file. that i am running, when i print sys.argv[1] it shows the index out of order

Comment: @KarlKnechtel loading the dataset files and convert to dataframe for combining these to a new dataset file.

Comment: @angel When you run the script from the command line, it expects to receive two file paths as command line arguments.

Comment: @dspencer okay, so what should i want to do??

Comment: How are you running the script? Where are your data files?

Comment: @dspencer i am running the scirpt in the terminal, and my data files and python  file is stored in same folder

Comment: Based on what you show, you need to run the script using `python SCRIPT_NAME FILEPATH1 FILEPATH2`, where `SCRIPT_NAME` is the name of your python module, `FILEPATH1` is your first data file and `FILEPATH2` is your second.

Comment: @dspencer when i run the script like what you say, i am getting following :   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 361, in _inferSchema
    first = rdd.first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1381, in first
    raise ValueError("RDD is empty")
ValueError: RDD is empty